# Spring kafka , Does ConsumerSeekAware interface, onPartitionsAssigned method call when rebalancing

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka

Does ConsumerSeekAware  interface, onPartitionsAssigned method call  when rebalancing. Because I want to seek to specific offset which are in the offset when initializing and rebalancing. Could I use  consumerSeekAware for both purposes or should I use ConsumerRebalanceListener for rebalancing purpose. Please give simple answers because I don't have depth knowledge about spring kafka yet. If you could please provide a sample code. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ConsumerSeekAware` has this method:

```
/**
 * When using group management, called when partition assignments change.
 * @param assignments the new assignments and their current offsets.
 * @param callback the callback to perform an initial seek after assignment.
 */
void onPartitionsAssigned(Map<TopicPartition, Long> assignments, ConsumerSeekCallback callback);
```

It is called from the `KafkaMessageListenerContainer.seekPartitions(Collection<TopicPartition> partitions, boolean idle)`, which, in turn, from the `ConsumerRebalanceListener.onPartitionsAssigned()` internal implementation. And thew last one has this JavaDocs:

```
 * A callback method the user can implement to provide handling of customized offsets on completion of a successful
 * partition re-assignment. This method will be called after an offset re-assignment completes and before the
 * consumer starts fetching data.
```

So, yes, `ConsumerSeekAware.onPartitionsAssigned()` is always called during rebalancing. By the way there is no such a state for Apache Kafka as `initializing`. It is always `rebalancing` - the broker is in waiting state and starts rebalancing whenever a new consumer is joined.

Comment: May be this should be a another question. Does kafka call , ConsumerSeekAware.onPartitionsAssigned() method for each consumer (If there are four consumers , does kafka call this method , four times). Does  @param assignments contain  topicPartions  of one consumer. If it is necessary i will post this as a another question.

Comment: If you have  less partitions than consumers, so that `onPartitionsAssigned()` really might not be called for some consumers because there is just not enough partition to distribute. That's not clear why do you say `4 times`, since it is really once per consumer if any.

Comment: If there are partitions more than consumers and if there are x number of consumers  what will happen ?.  Does that method call for each consumer ( does that method call x times). If that method call for each consumer,does  that assignment parameter contain all the topic partitions of that consumer.

Comment: No, the parameter has what Broker has assigned to the consumer. It really can be several partitions, but not all of them. And I said you already: that method may not be called if you have more consumers than partitions. Please, read Apache Kafka docs for details